# Make alias for a class in the same file as the class

Tags: python, alias

Suppose I have a class `ReallyLongClassName`, shown here:

```py
class ReallyLongClassName:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.items = [*args]
        self.length = len(self.items)
```

If I was importing this class into another file, I could do this:

```
from somefile import ReallyLongClassName as ShorterClassName
```

Here, an alias is created for this class. But suppose I wanted to create an alias for the class **in the same file as the class itself**, so that calling the original class name does not work? I know you can save the class to a new variable and delete the old class, like this:

```
class ReallyLongClassName:
    # stuff here

ShorterName = ReallyLongClassName
del ReallyLongClassName
```

But can you use `as` to rename the class in the same file as the class itself?

Comment: Isn't that what you're doing with `ShorterName = ReallyLongClassName`? What is the problem with that?

Comment: When you use `as` with an imported module or class, you cannot reference the original name of the module or class. Thus you have to delete the old class name to have the same effect as `as` does when you import a module.

Comment: If making a new variable and deleting the old name of the class is the only way to do it, I would like to know

Comment: But what is the difference between what you have and what you want? Why do you want something different?

Comment: I want to know if there is a shorter way to change the name of a class

Comment: No. No there isn't. I'm not sure why you would want to do all of this to begin wtih. Why not just `ShorterName = ReallyLongClassName`?

Comment: Note, `from somefile import ReallyLongClassName as ShorterClassName` **does not** do `ShorterName.__name__ = ShorterName.__qualname__ = "ShorterName"`